# How can I pull a URL from my mysql database and pass it into a thymeleaf template as an img src?

Tags: java, hibernate, url, thymeleaf

I am building an application with Hibernate and Thymeleaf. I have an object for Image urls so the user can put in the url and it gets pulled from the database and put into the template as th:src

The problem I am ending up with is instead of it pulling the url from the database it is trying to use it as a local directory or something. The links in my db include http:// or https:// which I've seen referenced as a problem in other questions asked.

http://localhost:8080/com.liftoff.thymeleafrecipeproject.demo.models.Image@24

This is what I am getting as the Image url, what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the code you use to retrieve the URL and how you parse it. Please also show us an example of what is stored in the database (Is it a full working link that can be pasted directly into a browser?).

Comment: this `com.liftoff.thymeleafrecipeproject.demo.models.Image@24` looks like the `toString()` of a `models.Image` object, and not the actual (String) link.